# Core data - Searches for a single object that has a given identifier

Tags: search, core-data, swiftui

I am creating an application in SwiftUI that will be a songbook. I would like, from the view where I have the song content, to click on a button so that a window appears where I can enter the number of the song I want to switch to (each song has its own number). After typing in the number, it's supposed to take me to a view where the song content for that number is. I'm not quite able to pull a song with a given number from the database and display it in the view. Below I am sending my code. I am counting on your help.

CoreData Model:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuZ5w.png)

PersistenceController:

```
struct PersistenceController {
static let shared = PersistenceController()
let container: NSPersistentContainer

init() {
    container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")
    container.loadPersistentStores { (description, error) in
        if let error = error {
            fatalError("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}

func save(completion: @escaping (Error?) -> () = {_ in}) {
    let context = container.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
            completion(nil)
        } catch {
            completion(error)
        }
    }
}
    
func delete(_ object: NSManagedObject, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> () = {_ in}) {
    let context = container.viewContext
    context.delete(object)
    save(completion: completion)
}

func getSong(number: String) -> Song {
    var song = Song()
    let context = container.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Song")
    request.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(format: "number <> '\(number)'")
    
    do {
        song = try context.fetch(request) as? Song ?? Song()
      } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
      }
    return song
}
```

}

DetailView (a view in which we have the content of the song):

```
struct DetailView: View {
@State var isSelected: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(song.content ?? "No content")
                .padding()
            Spacer()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("\(song.number). \(song.title ?? "No title")", displayMode: .inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                HStack{
                    Button(action: {
                        song.favorite.toggle()
                        isSelected=song.favorite
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(isSelected ? .red : .blue)
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    searchView()
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
func searchView(){
    
    let search = UIAlertController(title: "Go to the song", message: "Enter the number of the song you want to jump to.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    search.addTextField {(number) in
        number.placeholder = "Song number"
    }
    let go = UIAlertAction(title: "Go", style: .default) { (_) in
        let song = PersistenceController.shared.getSong(number: (search.textFields![0].text)!)
        DetailView(song: song, isSelected: song.favorite)
    }
    
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive) { (_) in
        print("Cancel")
    }
    search.addAction(cancel)
    search.addAction(go)
    UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(search, animated: true, completion: {
    })
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getSong` method cannot work, the predicate is wrong, the fetch returns always an array, and it's highly recommended to specify the static type of the entity rather than unspecified `NSFetchRequestResult`

And as `song` is obviously an `NSManagedObject` subclass you cannot create an instance with the default initializer `Song()`. Better return an optional

```
func getSong(number: String) -> Song? {
    guard let songNumber = Int64(number) else { return nil }
    let context = container.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<Song>(entityName: "Song")
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "number == %ld", songNumber)
    
    do {
        return try context.fetch(request).first
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance and help. I still have a problem with the view let me reload.

Comment: It's unclear where does `song` come from in the body of `DetailView`? At least you need a `@State` property or a `@Binding`

Comment: I added @State to the song variable and renamed the song variable in the searchView function to songFound.

Comment: It displays an alert and in it we enter the number by which we are looking for an object and this object is returned by the getSong function. Up to this point everything is working fine. The problem I have encountered is that it now calls view and passes this found object, but the view does not refresh.

Comment: If `song` is a `@State` property it should cause a refresh on change.

Comment: I added @State (@State var song : Song). Maybe the view invocation itself is incorrect.                                                                                                                   `let go = UIAlertAction(title: "Go", style: .default) { (_) in
            let songFound = PersistenceController.shared.getSong(number: (search.textFields![0].text)!)
            DetailView(song: songFound!, isSelected: songFound!.favorite)
        }`

Comment: Please ask a new question. And don't force unwrap the result of  `getSong`. If there is no song the code will crash.